# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Multiple Rows Formatting Based on range

Tags: google-sheets, match

I wish to conditionally format cells within a range based on another range...
Eg: format `D7:I7` if a value is found in `D19:I19`.
I've looked but couldn't find a way...
Tried both `HLOOKUP`& `MATCH`:

```
=HLOOKUP(D7,D$24:I$24,,FALSE)
=MATCH(D$7,D$24:I$24,0)`
```

I have also tried a simple `=D$19:I$19` - this one returns only partial formatting on the ranges selected - `E9`, `G11`, `H13`....
Ideas??
[image: HLOOKUP]
[image: SIMPLE COMPARE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applies to range: `D7:I7`

**Custom formula is**: `=countif($D19:$I19,$D$7)>0`